# Web api with multiple routes controller/{path}&{path}

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, routes

I'm trying to create a Web api that allows me to get all books with a price between two different values.

So by entering `api/books/price/30.0&35.0` I shall return all books `with price between '30.0' och '35.0' sorted by price`. My code looks the following.

```
[HttpGet("price")]
    public ActionResult GetBooksSortedByPrice()
    {
        var book = FindBooksSortedByPrice();
        if (book is null) return NotFound();
        return Ok(book);
    }
    [HttpGet("price/{price}")]
    public IActionResult GetBookByPrice(double price)
    {
        var book = FindBookByPrice(price);
        if (book is null) return NotFound();
        return Ok(book);
    }
    //returns books from requested price
    private IEnumerable<Book> FindBookByPrice(double price)
    {
        //var allBooksBetweenPrices = _bookList.Where(_bookList => (_bookList.Price >= firstPrice) && (_bookList.Price <= secondPrice));
        //return allBooksBetweenPrices;
        return _bookList.Where(_bookList => _bookList.Price.Equals(price));
    }
    private IEnumerable<Book> FindBooksSortedByPrice()
    {
        return _bookList.OrderBy(b => b.Price).Where(_bookList => _bookList.Price.Equals(_bookList.Price));

    }
```

I know I will probably get told my routing could be better, but as I do not understand the guide's I've read completely I'm very glad to receieve a smaller explanation (with a code example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use 2 input parameters for price instead of one

```
[Route("price/{minprice}/{maxprice}")]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Book>> GetBooksSortedByPrice(double minPrice, double maxPrice)
    {
        var books = FindBooksSortedByPrice(minPrice, double maxPrice);
        if (books== null) return NotFound();
        return Ok(books);
    }

[NonAction]
 private IEnumerable<Book> FindBookByPrice(ddouble minPrice, double maxPrice)
    {
  return _bookList
.Where(b => (b.Price >= minPrice) && (b.Price <= maxPrice))
.OrderBy(o=>o.Price)
.ToArray();
        
    }
```